# As a noun I’m complete; as a verb, I’m yet to be so

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> Removing my prefix
>   Makes a familiar sound
>   Removing my infix
>   Helps you search all around
>
> Removing my suffix
>   Means to make me whole
>   As a noun I’m complete
>   As a verb I’m yet to be so

Who am I?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are

> building

Removing my prefix \ Makes a familiar sound

> ding

Removing my infix \ Helps you search all around

> bing (really?)

Removing my suffix \ Means to make me whole

> build

As a noun I’m complete \ As a verb I’m yet to be so

> A 'building' is a complete structure, while 'building' it, it's unfinished.

Comment: Would never have guessed the 2nd part of the first paragraph, well done!

Comment: Yes, bing is quite amazing...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a stretch but

> fashion

which as a verb  isn't done until in the past tense.   '

But as a noun represent the item or the concept.

As I said,  a stretch because there isn't any prefix or suffix.

Comment: Hey there new user! I'd recommend spacing out each line into it's own explanation, like the other answer did, to explain why you think this is the answer.

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks for the hint; hope it's better now